# Position Flex Item at Bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML and CSS so sorry if this was a simple question. This is a image of what I am trying to achieve

Picture of number of clients and years of experience

[image]

And this is what I managed to make

[image: What I managed to do]

My Question is how do I align the text) to the same level as the number

```css
.experience {
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.number-text {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.clients {
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="experience">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">
        12
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number-text">Years Of <br> Experience.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clients">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">
        14
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number-text">Satisfied <br> Clients.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.number-text { display:flex; align-items:center; height:100%; }`  Should do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

you can use `position: relative;` and use `top` CSS property for moving down the text

I used a `rem` value for the `top` property, because if you `px` it not will be working for all devices.

```css
.number-text {
    /* here the trick */
    position: relative;
    top: 0.8rem;
}
```

---

I see also that you don't use the DRY method

> DON'T REPEAT YOURSELF

do this instead

```css
.experience,
.clients {

/* your CSS */

}
```

I also added the same colors you put in the image in reusable CSS variables

```css
* {
    --bg-color-blue: #252734;
    --gold-orange: #e9b258;
}
```

that's it here the code

```css
* {
  --bg-color-blue: #252734;
  --gold-orange: #e9b258;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color-blue);
}

.experience,
.clients {
  color: var(--gold-orange);
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.number-text {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  /* here the trick */
  position: relative;
  top: 0.8rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- first parent -->
    <div class="experience">
      <div class="col-lg-auto">
        <p class="number">
          12
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto">
        <p class="number-text">Years Of <br> Experience.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second parent -->
    <div class="clients">
      <div class="col-lg-auto">
        <p class="number">
          14
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto">
        <p class="number-text">Satisfied <br> Clients.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what going wrong with DRY? @mplungjan

Comment: the acronym is written good like I see on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: The poster asked for the text to be bottom aligned with the text, not centered.

Comment: ok. I will change

Comment: @dantheman is the new answer good? :)

Comment: This answer was so long, please shorten it a bit

Comment: @mplungjan shorted the answer to the correct one

Comment: @TrueAlpha shorted the answer, now have only the good one

Answer (score 1):

Your html is far too complex for this and all the other answers are incorrect as they are centering the text rather than aligning it with the bottom of the text. You can do this properly using `align-items: last baseline;`.

```css
.client {
  display: flex;
  align-items: last baseline;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.text {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="client">
  <div class="number">14</div>
  <div class="text">
   Years Of <br> Experience.
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you need to use your html then you can do it like this:

```css
.experience, .clients {
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: last baseline;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.number-text {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.clients {
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="experience">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">
        12
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number-text">Years Of <br> Experience.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clients">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">
        14
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number-text">Satisfied <br> Clients.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got a linter error saying: Expected (flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch) but found 'last baseline'.

Comment: then you need to upgrade your linter as this is supported by all modern browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#browser_compatibility

Answer (score -1):

The following code should work. Just add the align-items:center; property to the .experience div.

```
.experience{
align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `align-self: center` on the container to be centred.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #000000;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
}

.experience {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.number-text {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.clients {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  margin: 0; // set margin to zero
  // the p tag has a margin by default that you have to remove
}
  
  
.align-self-center {
  align-self: center; make the container align itself to center
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="experience">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto align-self-center">
      <p class="number-text">
        Years Of <br />
        Experience.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clients">
    <div class="col-lg-auto">
      <p class="number">12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-auto align-self-center">
      <p class="number-text">
        Satisfied <br />
        Clients.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```